Any OS selection runs Windows instead of selected OS
I installed ubuntu22 alongside windows11 on (Lenovo Ideapad3), while installing I selected "use ubuntu alongside windows". So I did it. But for some personal reason I deleted the grub from windows command prompt. My plan is to install another linux os in the machine. But, I guess, because I unistalled grub using windows cmd, I am unable to boot from USB drive. So I tried (unetbootin)[https://unetbootin.github.io/] and burnt an image (CentOS7). But even after that if I select that to boot, it says windows is broken.
So, if I select USB it loads windows, if I select unetbootin it selects windows too... what to do so that I can use linux in dualboot setup?
